# condensing repeated ng-model based on ng-if

Tags: html, angularjs, razor

I have a block of angular code:

```
<input ng-if="item.isBulk" ng-model="item.BulkQuantity" />
 .
 .
<input ng-if="item.isCollection" ng-model="item.CollectionQuantity" />
```

Adhering to the principle of [***DRY***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself),
Is there a way to reduce this to a **one liner in** `html` ***without javascript***?
(*actual code has more attributes and a few more inputs that differ only on values

supplied to `ng-if` and `ng-model`.*)
**Edit**:
Only 1 `input` will evaluate to `true`.
Having some experience with `React`'s `JSX` and implementing this in conjunction with
***MS ASP's Razor View*** I felt that this is possible.
With `Razor` you can inline code with html and
`JSX` you have javascript '*wrapping*' html.

Comment: short answer, no, this isn't something Angular or HTML supports.  besides the fact that your code doesn't demonstrate what it would do if both conditions were true if the conditions were consolidated to a single line....

Comment: Only one would be true. Will update the question, when there is time.

Answer (score 1):

*HTML does not support conditional logic*.
Be in mind that HTML is a markup language. You would need to use client-side scripting or server-side code to provide the conditional logic that would render your HTML accordingly.

Keep rocking!